# Gravitational force: Two identical spheres in contact

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, textbook-erratum

This question, and its supplied answer, is getting on my nerves (more so, because of the answer):

> Two identical spheres of radius $R$ are kept in contact. Obtain a relation between gravitational force and the radius of the spheres.

That's pretty much all that the question says.

---

From my experience working out questions on this topic (Gravitation) from the same workbook, by "gravitational force", I assume they're referring to "net gravitational force between the two bodies". Also, by "identical spheres", I'm assuming (drawing from experience with other questions in the book, again) they mean "Identical, uniform spheres".

Instinctively, I quickly jotted down

$${F}\propto{1/R^2}$$

Quite easy to come up with, really... two identical, uniform spheres in contact will have their centers of mass separated by a distance of $R$ + $R$ = $2R$, and the rest is Newton's law of universal gravitation,

$$F =  \frac {G.M.m}{d^2}$$

---

But here's the catch:

The supplied answer follows a different rationale, to arrive at a totally different relation.

> $$F =  \frac {G.M.m}{d^2}$$
>
> => $$F =  \frac {G.M.M}{(2R)^2}$$
>
> Since mass can be expressed as the product of density ($ρ$) and volume ($V$),
>
> => $$F =  \frac {G.(ρ)[(4/3)πR^3].(ρ)[(4/3)πR^3]}{(2R)^2}$$
>
> => $${F}\propto\frac{R^6}{R^2}$$
>
> => $${F}\propto{R^4}$$

---

I was incredulous at first.

"Gravitational force is *directly* proportional to the *fourth* power of distance?! Nuts!"

However, after calming down a bit I realized that what I was looking at wasn't *total* baloney.

I can see a "constraint" here: The two spheres must be kept in contact.

So if the radius *increases*, so would the mass. And if the mass increases, so would the gravitational force between the spheres.

Why *my* answer (inverse square law) would be "wrong" here, is because when I take up the center of mass argument, it doesn't consider the "contact" constraint.

---

**So is the answer supplied in the book correct? If so, is it for the same reasons as I've mentioned? Or am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that the question doesn't give enough information.

One approach is to assume the spheres have the same mass whatever their radius.  Thus the force is as you calculated, goes as $1/R^2$

The other approach is to assume the spheres have constant density whatever the radius. In this case the masses change as the radius changes, and as such the force goes as $R^4$.

So, in a way, both answers are right.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational force is proportonal to fourth power not of distance but radius when the spheres touch, not when they are separated or come closer.